# PLSQL Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Can someone tell me why am I getting the following error when I run this script:

```
DECLARE
    some_string VARCHAR2(30)    := 'Some String';
    V_CNT   NUMBER := null; 
    v_msg varchar2(4000) := ''; 
BEGIN
    v_msg := 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ' || V_CNT || ' FROM table_name WHERE column_name = ' || upper(some_string);
    execute immediate v_msg; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_CNT);
END;
/
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: As you're starting out with PL/SQL you should try to make friends with the Oracle documentation. It will help you resolve this sort of syntax bloomer. For instance [here is the chapter for Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this example (based on actual Scott's tables & values, not *generic* ones). Basically, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` should look different - use both `USING` and `INTO`. Also, no need to declare variables *null* (or empty strings).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2      some_string varchar2(30) := 'MANAGER';
  3      v_cnt       number;
  4      v_msg       varchar2(4000);
  5  begin
  6    v_msg := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE job = :a';
  7
  8    execute immediate v_msg into v_cnt using some_string;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line(v_cnt);
 11  end;
 12  /
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This works great. But what if I want to display the entire `SELECT` statement as a debug message? Meaning, including both lines 6 & 8 as a String.

Comment: As line 7, include `dbms_output.put_Line(replace(v_msg, ':a', some_string));`

Answer (score 0):

Use as the following

```
DECLARE
 some_string VARCHAR2(30)    := 'Some String';
 V_CNT   NUMBER := null; 
 v_msg varchar2(4000) := ''; 
BEGIN

     v_msg := 'SELECT COUNT(*)  
                 FROM table_name 
                WHERE column_name = ''' || upper(some_string)||''''; 
             -- more quotes needed, I'm printing result of the decent v_msg also.

     execute immediate v_msg into v_cnt; -- you should shift "into v_cnt" here.

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_msg);
     ---> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'Some String'
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cnt);    
END;
```

*P.S. You can get the result as above, but I also suggest you to use bind variables( because of security and performance reasons ) as in the @Littlefoot 's case.*

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with this:

1. `V_CNT` is `null` and you don't assign any value to it, so the part qwith it becomes:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO FROM
   ```

which causes error I think.

2. You don't have apostrophes in `where` clause, which also may lead to further errors. You should use:

   ```
   'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ' || V_CNT || ' FROM table_name WHERE column_name = ''' || upper(some_string) || '''';
   ```